# Android Studio: XmlRpcClientException Failed to parse servers response: Unexpected non-whitespace character data

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, odoo, xml-rpc

So i'm traying to connect my application with an odoo database  in android studion with an odoo External API "XML-RPC" to get data from the database, I was able to connect and i get the user Id successfuly, i was also able to search and create normaly, but when i'm trayin to read any thing from the database, this exception keep showing. and i can't find any thing that he can help me.
So please is there any one who can tell me where i am mestaking ?

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        final String db = "BTP_p",
        username = "admin",
        password = "_chantier";
        final String url ="http://sogesi.hopto.org";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new DemoTask().execute(url);


}
class DemoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {


    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(final String... url) {

        final XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
        final XmlRpcClientConfigImpl common_config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();

        try {
            //Testé l'authentification
            common_config.setServerURL(
                    new URL(String.format("%s/xmlrpc/2/common", url)));

            int uid = (int)client.execute(
                    common_config, "authenticate", asList(
                            db, username, password, emptyMap()));
            Log.d("result", "*******************************************************************");
            Log.d("uid = ", Integer.toString(uid));


            //Testé la liste des recordes d'une table
            final XmlRpcClient models = new XmlRpcClient() {{
                setConfig(new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl() {{
                    setServerURL(new URL(String.format("%s/xmlrpc/2/object",url)));
                }});
            }};


            final List id = asList((Object[])models.execute(
                    "execute_kw", asList(
                            db, uid, password,
                            "project.chantier", "search",
                            asList(asList(
                                    asList("state", "=", "en_cour"))),
                            new HashMap() {{
                                put("limit", 1);
                            }}
                            )));

            //this is the ligne where the exception is rising
            final Map record = (Map)((Object[])models.execute(
                    "execute_kw", asList(
                            db, uid, password,
                            "project.chantier", "read",
                            asList(id)
                    )
            ))[0];

           return (Integer) uid;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d("MalformedURLException", "*********************************************************");
            Log.d("MalformedURLException", e.toString());
        }  catch (XmlRpcException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO: do something with the feed
    }
}
```

}

[This is the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ov8f.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I had to download and import this three libraries :

```
exist-dependency-ws-commons-util-1.0.2.jar
xmlrpc-client-3.1.jar
xmlrpc-common-3.1.jar
```